# QTextEdit add an abbreviate system

Tags: html, c++, qt, qtextedit, qcompleter

I'm currently working on a text editor, I want to create an abbreviate system. I mean for example when you write html5 then press key tab for example you expand an code like this :

```
<html> 
   <body>
    ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Maybe I used the wrong keyword but I don't know how to make a function like this. I found the QCompleter class but it seems more for completion than an abbreviate system.

Can anyone help me ? 
Best regards,
zed13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could define a bunch of constant strings that are literally the markups you want to use. E.g..:

```
const QString html5tab = "<html>\n\t<body>\n\t...\n\t</body>\n</html>";
```

I'm probably missing some necessary escapes, but that is the gist of it. Then write your program so that when the tab button gets pressed, the variable `html5tab` gets printed to the text edit field.

Anyway, that's the first thing that comes to mind.